# Ficus decora leaf spots and dead tips

Tags: pruning, fungus, ficus

apologies if this question has been already asked elsewhere.

I have some black spots underneath the leaves of my ficus decora, which I presume are a fungal infection (cercospora?) Could someone please help me confirm if this is the case, and if so, which fungicide you've had luck with?
[image: Black spots under leaves]

My bigger concern is that all the growing tips are brown and seem dead. I've been using a moisture meter to make sure I'm not overwatering, so I don't think it's a moisture problem. There's a ficus elastica right next to it that is thriving, so I don't think it's a lighting problem either. [image: Dead growing tips]

Should I trim off these dead tips to encourage new growth, or just be patient while the plant recovers?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Edit: I recently discovered some mealybugs on the leaves, so perhaps the black spots were due to them, rather than a fungus?